# Find an appropriate function such that the composition is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measureable function.

Show there exists an $\omega:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
 $$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}\omega(t)=\infty$$ and $g(t)=\omega(f(t)) $ is integrable on $[0,1]$

Hint: consider the sets $ A_k =\left \{ x: k\leq f(x) < k+1 \right \}$

Any hints or directions? I'm at a loss, the limit condition seems to make it difficult.

Also, I wonder if there's such an omega that is approaching minus infinity at minus infinity.

Comment: By the way if you've seen this problem elsewhere in some literature I would love to know where.

Comment: f is not integrable though, simply measureable

Comment: Should the $x$ in the limit actually be a $t$? Otherwise it doesn't make sense. Then the identity wouldn't work because $\omega$ must tend towards infinity.

Comment: sounds interesting, post the comment as answer and get the credit :)

Comment: @MaikPickl Woops of course you're right, I think for some silly reason I thought you'd meant the function which is 1 everywhere... it's been a long day!

Comment: I think it was great, what was the problem? You've been great help BTW.

Comment: A bounded measurable function on a set of finite measure is integrable. And the function is measurable because it is measurable on each of the measurable components we defined it on. I think it's a known lemma!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume $f:[0,1]\to [0,\infty).$ Because $\sum \mu (A_k) <\infty,$ there exist positive $b_k$ such that $b_k \to \infty$ and $\sum b_k\mu (A_k)<\infty.$ Define $\omega (t) = b_k$ for $t\in [k,k+1).$ Then $\omega \to \infty$ at $\infty.$ We have $\omega \circ f = \sum b_k\chi_{A_k}.$ Thus $\omega \circ f$ is measurable, and

$$\int_0^1 \omega \circ f \, d\mu = \sum b_k\mu (A_k)<\infty.$$

Comment: where did you use that f is non-negative?

Comment: I assumed it to keep everything simple at first. The idea extends easily to $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R.$

Comment: thanks btw. my question is did you actually use it?

Comment: Yes, because we didn't have to worry about positive and negative values of f

Comment: Could you say maybe one or two words about the existence of the $b_k$? How does this follow from $\sum \mu(A_k) < \infty$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure: We can choose $k_1 < k_2 < \dots $ such that

$$\sum_{k=k_j}^{\infty} \mu(A_k) < 1/2^j.$$

For $k_j\le k < k_{j+1},$ define $b_k = j.$ Then $b_k \to \infty.$ We then have

$$\sum_{k=k_1}^{\infty} b_k\mu(A_k) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k_j\le k < k_{j+1}}b_k\mu(A_k) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} j\sum_{k_j\le k < k_{j+1}}\mu(A_k) \le \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} j\sum_{k=k_j}^\infty \mu(A_k)\le \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} j/2^j < \infty.$$

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this! I guess this "construction" of the $b_k$ works with arbitrary convergent series as well, or am I wrong?

Comment: Sure, it works for any convergent nonnegative series.